# How to get all Jackson/JAXB annotated property values?

Tags: java, json, reflection, jaxb, annotations

Given an entity (model) class with Jackson annotations for setting column names:

```
public class GridRowModel {
    private Long maxRegulatedValue;

    @JsonProperty(value="Max Regulated Value")
    public Long getMaxRegulatedValue() {
        return maxRegulatedValue;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value="Fares")
    public Map<String, FareModel> getFares() {
        return fares;
    }
    ...
```

*(Could alternatively have used JAXB annotations - e.g. @XmlElement(name="Max Regulated Value").*

I need a `getGridColumns` method that will return a JSON structure with all the column names extracted from this model + its submodels (so here it would return "Max Regulated Value" and all `@JsonProperty` values from `FareModel`.)

The question is how best to approach this? Have mooted using reflection, e.g. something like `method.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value())` but not sure if this would even work and it doesn't seem ideal. For one thing, it wouldn't respect the order specified by `@JsonPropertyOrder` (or `propOrder` in JAXB). Am wondering if there is a smarter way (perhaps using some kind of Adapter?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the column order turned out to be important so I annotated each model class with:

@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "Max Regulated Value",
    "Another field",
    ... })

...and then wrote a method to loop through these (using reflection) + the submodel (which is actually fixed).